# jQuery preload for images linked to via href

Tags: jquery

I have linked image src form href and added navigation to image now my image is loading very slow so i need to preload the images which href linked to img src.

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set all those images in the bottom of the first page with 0px width like
          
That's the easy way and worked well for me